# How to prevent Google Scholar from reformatting the name of a consortium to the Last, First format

Tags: google-scholar

I am trying to edit entries on my personal Google Scholar page. The process is smooth but Google Scholar automatically reformats any author name I enter to appear in the Last, First format. For example, if I add "Example Consortium" as an author, Google Scholar will list this as "E Consortium". How do I stop this reformatting?

Comment: Have you tried reading Google's documentation?

Comment: How is that Last, First? Isn't it F. Last?